# How do I let my friends join my single player world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

Ok, So I have a friend who lives in the Netherlands and I want her to join my single player world to record and RP (Role Play). I gave her my port number at first, but that didn't work, so I did command R and typed in cmd and then ipconfig. I then got my IPv4 number and gave her that, but she still can't join. I'm kind of a noob when it comes to this stuff so please help as soon as possible!!!

Comment: Like answered, it isn't possible via LAN. I would recommend using something like [Grappl](http://grappl.io). With Grappl, you open you LAN and Grappl sets up a secure server address that you can give to your friend. Source: Personal use across US.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: It's not possible.

Well, at least not if you only use the single player client. The normal client can only be used for LAN, not for internet-lobbies. You could use the minecraft server software - or better bukkit/spigot.

Install Spigot (which you can download [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-installation/)) on your local machine as described in the spigot docs and after that, you have to port-forward the port which minecraft should use in your router (which obviously requires you to have full access to the router). After you did that, you can copy the world from your `AppData/Roaming/.minecraft` folder into the world folder of your server.

Since running a server requires quite a quite a bit of technical knowledge and usage of console commands and you are kind of a noob as you said yourself, you might be better off with renting a server from a provider like [nitrado](http://server.nitrado.net/eng/rent-gameserver) since they provide an easy to handle Web-GUI for your server.

Edit:

You can also install the native mc server software, which is described pretty nicely [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/202958/how-to-run-a-simple-local-minecraft-server-with-and-without-mods/).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from your question, I assume you yourself do not live in the Netherlands? You cannot actually host a server away from LAN simply using the client. You will need to have some server software. For your purposes, it is most likely that you would want to run a vanilla type server. This will require port-forwarding, and there are many videos on how to specifically do it for your ISP. As you stated that you are a bit of a noob, I wouldn't recommend jumping into Spigot/Bukkit until you have a little bit of experience with servers. The vanilla server will suit your needs, if they are just to RP and record. Spigot plugins mostly affect gameplay, and they tend to get complicated around the backend. On one more note, I wouldn't suggest paying for a server hosted by someone else, unless your computer is VERY bad. And again, since you are wanting to do RPing and Recording, paying for a server to run 24/7 is probably not the best option.

**TL;DR**

1. Go online, look up a video explaining how to set up a Vanilla Server.
2. Stay away from Spigot/Bukkit at first.
3. Stay away from purchasing a 24/7 server.

(EDIT: Sniped.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I appreciate it! No, I don't live in the Netherlands. That is a huge problem as mods in this RP are vital. I was going to create a forge server but my dad said hackers could, well, hack and get my network code and stuff and it wouldn't be good. I just don't know if this is possible. We have been planning this for ages now. Thanks for your help anyway.